# Symfony update fails with YAML errors

Tags: php, symfony, yaml

I have a web application currently running on Symfony 4.3.5 without any problems.

I call "php composer.phar update" in my project directory. Composer starts to download and upgrade packages to version 4.4 and finally fails with

---

```
Executing script cache:clear [KO]
 [KO]
Script cache:clear returned with error code 1
!!  
!!  In FileLoader.php line 180:
!!                                                                                 
!!    The file "/home/markus/Programming/personal/config/packages/sonata_admin.ya  
!!    ml" does not contain valid YAML: Unexpected characters near "                
!!    - {                                                                          
!!        route: app_workflows_erzeugemassnahmen_index,                            
!!        label: "Fällige Massnahmen erstellen",                                   
!!        roles: [ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN, ROLE_ADMIN_WORKFLOWS]                          
!!      }" at line 76 (near "  }") in /home/markus/Programming/personal/config/pa  
!!    ckages/sonata_admin.yaml (which is loaded in resource "/home/markus/Program  
!!    ming/personal/config/packages/sonata_admin.yaml").                           
!!
```

It complains about the same error in In YamlFileLoader.php line 693: and In Inline.php line 94:

This "sonata_admin.yaml" file worked perfectly before. I use "yamllint" to check the file and it does not find anything wrong. I upload the file to online YAML checks and they don't find any problem.

Interesting observations:
- The message says that the error is in line 76 but the surrounding text shown is from line 48
- When I empty the file completely, the upgrade fails with nearly the same error in a completely different file

I use PHP 7.3 and most recent composer.
Any ideas?

Here is the config file:

```
---
# Sonata Admin Bundle
sonata_block:
  default_contexts: [cms]
  blocks:
    # enable the SonataAdminBundle block
    sonata.admin.block.admin_list: ~
    sonata.block.service.geburtstagsliste: ~
    sonata.block.service.vertragsliste: ~
    sonata.block.service.jubilare: ~
    sonata.block.service.konsistenzcheck: ~
    sonata.block.service.workflowstatistik: ~
    sonata.block.service.schulungsliste: ~
    # sonata.block.service.testblock: ~

sonata_admin:
  persist_filters: true
  # for hide mosaic view button on all screen using `false`
  show_mosaic_button: false
  title: "Personal Admin"
  title_logo: "/bundles/sonatauser/default_avatar.png"
  security:
    handler: sonata.admin.security.handler.role
  dashboard:
    groups:
      Stammdaten Workflows:
        icon: '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-close"></i>'
        roles: [ROLE_ADMIN_STAMMDATEN, ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN]
      Stammdaten:
        icon: '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-close"></i>'
        roles: [ROLE_ADMIN_STAMMDATEN, ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN]
      Schulungen:
        icon: '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-close"></i>'
        label: ~
        label_catalogue: ~
        items:
          - {route: app_schulungsplanung_list, label: "Schulungsplanung"}
          - admin.schulungsevent
        roles: [ROLE_ADMIN_SCHULUNGSPLANUNG, ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN]
      Workflows/Massnahmen:
        icon: '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-close"></i>'
        items:
          - {
            route: app_workflows_ausstehendemassnahmen_index,
            label: "Übersicht Massnahmen",
          }
          - {
            route: app_workflows_erzeugemassnahmen_index,
            label: "Fällige Massnahmen erstellen",
            roles: [ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN, ROLE_ADMIN_WORKFLOWS],
          }
        roles: [ROLE_USER_WORKFLOWS, ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN, ROLE_ADMIN_WORKFLOWS]
      Workflows/Offboarding:
        icon: '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-close"></i>'
        items:
          - {
            route: app_workflows_ereignisuebersicht_index,
            label: "Übersicht Offboarding",
          }
          - {
            route: app_bewertungen_bewertungenuebersicht_index,
            label: "Übersicht Bewertungen",
          }
        roles: [ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN, ROLE_ADMIN_WORKFLOWS]
      Workflows/Bewertungen:
        icon: '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-close"></i>'
        items:
          - {
            route: app_bewertungen_bewertungenuebersicht_index,
            label: "Übersicht Bewertungen",
          }
        roles: [ROLE_USER_ZEUGNISSE]
      Workflows/Onboarding:
        icon: '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-close"></i>'
        items:
          - {
            route: app_workflows_ereignisuebersicht_onboardinguebersicht,
            label: "Übersicht Onboarding",
          }
          - {
            route: app_onboardingwizard_onboardingwizard_index,
            label: "Onboarding Wizard",
          }
        roles: [ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN, ROLE_ADMIN_WORKFLOWS]
    blocks:
      - {
        position: left,
        type: sonata.block.service.geburtstagsliste,
        roles: [ROLE_PERSONAL, ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN],
      }
      - {
        position: left,
        type: sonata.block.service.workflowstatistik,
        roles: [ROLE_ADMIN_WORKFLOWS, ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN],
      }
      - {
        position: right,
        type: sonata.block.service.vertragsliste,
        roles: [ROLE_PERSONAL, ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN],
      }
      - {
        position: right,
        type: sonata.block.service.schulungsliste,
        roles: [ROLE_PERSONAL, ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN],
      }
      - {
        position: right,
        type: sonata.block.service.konsistenzcheck,
        roles: [ROLE_PERSONAL, ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN],
      }
      - {
        position: left,
        type: sonata.block.service.jubilare,
        roles: [ROLE_PERSONAL, ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN],
      }
```

Comment: It looks like a syntax error in your yaml file. Probably an indentation issue with the closing `}`. You you maybe post that config file or just the problematic segment from it?

Comment: I changed my post and added the config file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I'm just guessing here, that the reason is  the `{` and `}` in your multi-line mappings. What I don't get is that it ever worked ... (maybe the yaml-parser got stricter?)

Anyway, as far as I can tell the syntax definition appears to NOT require `{` and `}` if the mapping is split over multiple lines :

> ```
> -
>   name: Mark McGwire
>   hr:   65
>   avg:  0.278
> -
>   name: Sammy Sosa
>   hr:   63
>   avg:  0.288
> ```
>
> source: [2.1 Collections / Example 2.4, Sequence of Mappings](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2759963)

in fact, the only place where `{` follows a `-` in the spec is when the mapping is written in one line.

Sooo, maybe it's this.

Comment: Good job, Jakumi: You guessed right, this was exactly the problem. The next file had the same problem, that's why emptying the first file nevertheless caused a failure.
I really wonder why it worked that way since 2 years, to be hiones.honest.
Issue is solved, thanks!

Comment: A small note from my side: With you hint to remove the curly braces and split it over multiple lines with just the hyphen allowed me to upgrade to the recent Symfony version. Unfortunately my web app didn't work anymore afterwards - I had to change the multiline
```
-
  name: Mark
  hr: 65
```
to the following:
```
- {name:Mark,hr:65}
``
Without that Symfony/Sonata didn't find any configured admin services from services.yml.

Comment: @MarkusK. that does sound really weird. I honestly have no idea why this would happen. ;o/